# Mapping objects with Date and Timestamp with Orika

Tags: java, mapping, orika

I use Orika for mapping objects.

I want to format the fields Date and Timestamp with the format "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"

For the fields Date, I resolve the problem with:

```
    @Override
public void configure(final MapperFactory orikaMapperFactory) {

    orikaMapperFactory.getConverterFactory().registerConverter(new DateToStringConverter("yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"));

    orikaMapperFactory.classMap(OrderDTO.class, Order.class).byDefault().register();
}
```

But the fields TimeStamp I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve the problem with:

```
public class OrikaTimestampConverter extends CustomConverter<Timestamp, String> {

private final SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");

@Override
public String convert(Timestamp source, Type<? extends String> destinationType, MappingContext mappingContext) {

    Date date = new Date(source.getTime());

    return formatter.format(date);
} }
```

And added:

orikaMapperFactory.getConverterFactory().registerConverter(new OrikaTimestampConverter());